# Hide "Add to cart" button when the product price is zero

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an event based WordPress website on that I sell tickets using WooCommerce. Is there any way to hide the "add to cart" button for the product having cost zero?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You write this code in your theme `function.php`

```
function remove_add_to_cart_on_0 ( $purchasable, $product ){
        if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
            $purchasable = false;
        return $purchasable;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_on_0', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Its not working for me. Add to cart button is still there for cost zero events

Comment: @TaniyaSilhi change the priority 99 instead of 10 and try once again this code is working fine

Comment: I m Selling tickets using Woocommerce. I have added ticket price with cost zero but still it shows the cart option

Answer (score 1):

This may be a suitable solution according to the documentation

`woocommerce_is_purchasable` – filter
Function name: WC_Product::`is_purchasable`
`is_purchasable()` — Returns false if the product cannot be bought.
https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productis_purchasable/

```
function remove_add_to_cart_on_0 ( $is_purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->get_price() == 0 ) {
        return false; }
    else {
        return $is_purchasable; }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_on_0', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30903050)

Answer (score 0):

This code work like charm in function.php using this two filter.

```
add_filter('remove_add_to_cart', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function remove_add_to_cart($is_purchasable, $product) {
        if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
            $is_purchasable = false;
            return $purchasable;   
}


function remove_add_to_cart_on_0 ( $purchasable, $product ){
        if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
            $purchasable = false;
        return $purchasable;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_on_0', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The second function is doing all the work. The first function can be removed and has an incorrect order for the parameters of the add_filter function. Also "my_woocommerce_is_purchasable" is not a valid filter name.